# Terraform Gives errors Failed to load plugin schemas

Tags: amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

I have below code which I am using for create s3 bucket and cloud front in aws through terraform but terraform gives error.
I am using latest version of terraform cli exe for windows.
**Main.tf**
Please find below code of main.tf file :

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "3.70.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "aws" {
    access_key = "${var.aws_access_key}"
    secret_key = "${var.aws_secret_key}"
    region = "${var.aws_region}"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "mybucket" {
    bucket = "${var.bucket_name}"
    acl = "public-read"

    website {
        redirect_all_requests_to = "index.html"
    }

    cors_rule {
        allowed_headers = ["*"]
        allowed_methods = ["PUT","POST"]
        allowed_origins = ["*"]
        expose_headers = ["ETag"]
        max_age_seconds = 3000
    }

    policy = <<EOF
{
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicReadForGetBucketObjects",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::${var.bucket_name}/*"
        }
    ]
}
EOF
}

resource "aws_cloudfront_distribution" "distribution" {
    origin {
        domain_name = "${aws_s3_bucket.mybucket.website_endpoint}"
        origin_id   = "S3-${aws_s3_bucket.mybucket.bucket}"

        custom_origin_config  {
            http_port = 80
            https_port = 443
            origin_protocol_policy = "match-viewer"
            origin_ssl_protocols = ["TLSv1", "TLSv1.1", "TLSv1.2"]
        }
    }
    default_root_object = "index.html"
    enabled             = true

    custom_error_response {
        error_caching_min_ttl = 3000
        error_code            = 404
        response_code         = 200
        response_page_path    = "/index.html"
    }

    default_cache_behavior {
        allowed_methods  = ["DELETE", "GET", "HEAD", "OPTIONS", "PATCH", "POST", "PUT"]
        cached_methods   = ["GET", "HEAD"]
        target_origin_id = "S3-${aws_s3_bucket.mybucket.bucket}"

        forwarded_values {
            query_string = true

            cookies {
                forward = "none"
            }
      }

        viewer_protocol_policy = "allow-all"
        min_ttl                = 0
        default_ttl            = 3600
        max_ttl                = 86400
    }

    # Restricts who is able to access this content
    restrictions {
        geo_restriction {
            # type of restriction, blacklist, whitelist or none
            restriction_type = "none"
        }
    }

    # SSL certificate for the service.
    viewer_certificate {
        cloudfront_default_certificate = true
    }
}
```

Please find below error message:

```
Error: Failed to load plugin schemas
│
│ Error while loading schemas for plugin components: Failed to obtain provider schema: Could not load the schema for provider registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws: failed to retrieve schema
│ from provider "registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/aws": Plugin did not respond: The plugin encountered an error, and failed to respond to the plugin.(*GRPCProvider).GetProviderSchema call. The
│ plugin logs may contain more details...
```

Please help to resolve the issue , I'm new in terraforms.
**P.S.** This error generated while **terraform plan**

Comment: Are you getting this error message when attempting to run terraform init?

Comment: No, This error generate while terraform plan.

Comment: This message looks like the one Terraform generates when it isn't able to connect to the provider plugin at all. Terraform providers work as little temporary web servers that Terraform Core connects to over a socket, so one way this can happen is if you have some firewall software which is preventing Terraform Core from connecting to a provider, particularly on Windows where that connection happens to a TCP port on localhost. Do you have any firewall-like software on your system that might be preventing Terraform Core from connecting to the plugin?

Comment: @MartinAtkins Thanks for reviewing my question and given your valuable answer. So, is there any default port which terraform is using while terraform plan.

Comment: If you mean a TCP port then no, the port number is allocated automatically by the operating system when the plugin requests it, and then the plugin tells Terraform Core (via a different channel) which port it was allocated. The only certain thing is that (if you are on Windows) it will be a TCP port on localhost.

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: `terraform init` fixed it for me :D

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I had faced the same issue. The error was a little different tho. I was following the HashiCups provider example.

It happens when initializing it fails to upgrade or detect corrupt cached providers, or if you have changed the version but when you only run `terraform init` it finds the version in cache and decides to go with it. Delete the terraform directory and lock file, and then init again `terraform init -upgrade`

If you're on running it on Apple M1 chip, you might as well need to set this:

```
export GODEBUG=asyncpreemptoff=1;
```

https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/terraform-aws-provider-panic-plugin-did-not-respond/23396
https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/26104

Answer (score 4):

Using `chmod` to grant exec permissions to the providers, did the trick. Thank you for the article @dpiada!

Example:

```
chmod +x .terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/local/2.4.0/linux_amd64/terraform-provider-local_v2.4.0_x5
chmod +x .terraform/providers/registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/azurerm/3.55.0/linux_amd64/terraform-provider-azurerm_v3.55.0_x5
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm a beginner at terraform and I had same problem, so I hope this can help. I had same error "Failed to load plugin schemas" and I made a mess with `.terraform.lock.hcl` `.terraform`  files.
Here's what I did

1. I created new project at the path where I installed terraform and aws, and it was at “desktop” ..
   I don't know if that was necessary or not.
2. Then I created new two files `provider.tf`, and `main.tf` then I typed in terminal `terraform init`
   after that, it will automatically generate those files:
   `.terraform`
   `.terraform.lock.hcl`
   and I didn't change something on them. then run `terraform plan` in terminal.

here's my `provider.tf`

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
    }
  }
}

provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
  shared_config_files      = ["~/.aws/config"]
  shared_credentials_files = ["~/.aws/credentials"]
  profile                  = "terraform-user"
}
```

and here's `main.tf`

```
resource "aws_vpc" "vpc" {
    cidr_block = "10.123.0.0/16"
    enable_dns_hostnames = true
    enable_dns_support = true
    tags = {
        Name = "vpc"
    }
}
```

here's some other problems you may face too:
after you create `provider.tf` and `main.tf` then after running `terraform init` in terminal you get "no change", then you should save files before you run the commands in terminal.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem.

My problem was generated after re-install OS.
To arrive my solution I saw this article too: [enter link description here](https://support.hashicorp.com/hc/en-us/articles/4409220280339-Error-Could-not-load-plugin-permission-denied-or-exec-format-error)

I resolve it with following steps

`rm -rf .terraform`

`terraform init -backend-config="profile=##your_aws_profile"`

terraform recreates folder `.terraform' and update your aws provider plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem today, where I was getting the same error with terraform plan, apply or destroy commands.
After looking for easy solutions in vain, I decided to run terraform init and it solved the error. I was able to run terraform destroy to successfully destroy 52 resources. Phew!

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem and for me the issue was that I was running `terraform plan` from */home* where the partition mount point had "noexec" enabled.

You can simply run your terraform from somewhere else or disable the "noexec" from current mount point:

`vi etc/fstab` to edit and remove the noexec flag, change

`/dev/mapper/VG00-LVhome /home ext4 defaults,noexec,nosuid`

To

`/dev/mapper/VG00-LVhome /home ext4 defaults,nosuid`

And remount /home with `mount -o remount /home`

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I also got this issue too. I previously used Terraform's `time_static` resource ([link here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/time/latest/docs/resources/static)), ran an apply, then no longer needed it and removed it from my Terraform code, then tried to run a plan and got this error.

What fixed it for me was running `terraform state list`, finding the `time_static` resource in my Terraform state, then `terraform state rm` on the `time_static` resource, then deleted my `.terraform` directory, ran `terraform init` then `terraform plan` and this worked